# VirtualBox 6.0.10 cannot change the resolution in guest ubuntu (VBoxGuestAdditions is installed)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

There was a problem with changing the resolution in the guest Ubuntu on a virtual machine (Windows 10 host). It appeared immediately after updating VirtualBox to version 6.0.10 (it was updated either from version 6.0.6 or from 6.0.8).
The problem is that VirtualBox cannot change the screen resolution after installing VBoxGuestAdditions. Although for example a bi-directional clipboard works.
This problem manifested itself in the previously installed system (guest Ubuntu installed in the previous version of VB, used a resolution of 1600x900), as well as in the installed Ubuntu version 6.0.10 already.
Now both systems (and old with VB_6.0.6 and new) work with a resolution of 800x600. VBoxGuestAdditions is installed.
[image]

In the proprietary driver section, Ubuntu says:
[image]

You cannot switch to the manual driver, the “Apply Changes” button is not active.

Algorithm installation of the guest system:
1. A virtual machine has been created, all default settings, except - 4 cores, 128 MB of video memory, 3D acceleration, 4096 RAM. Standard Video Driver - VMSVGA
[image]
2. Launched a virtual machine, installed Ubuntu from an image from the Ubuntu site.
3. When I first started, I connected the guest system image (VBoxGuestAdditions) and installed it.
4. Reboot or off / on.

On the previous installation of Ubuntu, everything worked. After upgrading VirtualBox, the resolution does not change with the new installation, but the bi-directional buffer works in both systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a **BUG** in **6.0.10**. I rolled back to 6.0.8, rolled back (without checking) GuestAdditions to 6.0.8 and it all worked:

[image]

Proprietary drivers remain inactive:

[image]

Comment: has this bug been fixed since ? I still have the same issue running 6.1.6 on kubuntu